# How to turn on Automatic Closing Brace in VS-11

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I recently installed VS-11 on Windows 8 because my hard drive crashed, so I figured I'd go ahead and update from Win7 / VS10.  I would swear that the first time I started coding in VS-11 (C#), it automatically closed the braces, but then I changed some settings, and it stopped.  I can't find what setting I changed that made the difference.  Can anyone shed some light for me?  Thanks!

Comment: were you perhaps using addons that you haven't installed in VS11? R# comes to mind

Comment: No - it was a clean install of VS-11.  Maybe I'm wrong, but I'd swear that the first time I used it, it closed the brace.  If not, could it be that after all these years, Microsoft still hasn't added this option?

Comment: Ok - thanks.  Make it an answer and you get the points.  I did install the PPT but it seems to only have installed to VS-10.  Do you know of a way to get it to work on VS-11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know they still have not added this. You have to be using ReSharper or Microsoft's Productivity Power Tools

Edit: As far as I can see, the Power Tools is only supported on vs2010 right now, cant find any documentation for vs11